# How to create links with API data?

Tags: javascript, html, api

How can I create a href link that contains data from an API reference?

Example: the href link in my code below should look like this http://playrust.io/map/?Procedural%20Map_4000_383652508

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
      <script> players_cur1 = players_cur; players_max1 = players_max; entities1 = entities; is_online1 = is_online; map_size1 = map_size; map_seed1 = map_seed; fps1 = fps; </script>
      <script src="https://api.rust-servers.info/embed.js?id=3"></script>
      <script> players_cur2 = players_cur; players_max2 = players_max; entities2 = entities; is_online1 = is_online; map_size2 = map_size; map_seed2 = map_seed; fps2 = fps; </script>
  </head>
  
  <a target="_blank" href="http://playrust.io/map/?Procedural%20Map_<script>document.write(map_size1);</script>_<script>document.write(map_seed1);</script>">Map</a>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write it to the page:

```
document.write(`<a target="_blank" href="http://playrust.io/map/?Procedural%20Map_${map_size1}_${map_seed1}>Map</a>`);
```